# For new Cognos report do we need to use query studio or Report Studio?.Where to setup the query for the report?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm complete new to the Cognos BI. After the data modelling in Framework manager we publish the Cognos package to public folder. From there if we want to create a new report which one do we need to use?. Query Studio or Report Studio?. I know for every report there is a query attached. **where to setup this query** for the report?. Do we need to use Analysis Studio for the report building?.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis studio is for cubes or DMR (dimensionally modelled relational). I doubt your package is DMR. So don't use Analysis Studio (you'll find if you open your package in Analysis Studio you won't see anything)

Query Studio is for fast adhoc type reports with limited functionality

Report Studio is for advanced reports

You should be able to open your package in Query Studio or Report Studio.

Then you can drag and drop the columns from your package. You don't need to write SQL. You can write SQL if you like but the whole point of the package is so that you don't have to write SQL. You can just drag and drop, and the logic in the package knows how to aggregate and join tables etc.

I suggest you open Report Studio and try it. And read some training on Report Studio.

Comment: Nick is correct. Open Report Studio and start with a basic List report. Then drag and drop items from the package. Report Studio has the most robust set of report writing features.